# Number of distinct path in a graph with $n$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, trees

Let $T = (V , E)$ be a tree with $|V | = n\geqslant 2$. How many distinct paths are there (as sub graphs) in $T$?

I already have the answer to this question as $(n/2)$. The problem that I'm having is finding anything in the text that helps me to figure out how to arrive at this answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any two vertices of a tree are connected by a unique path, so there are exactly $\dbinom n2$ paths of length at least one. If you also count one-point paths (why wouldn't you?) there are $n$ of those, making a total of $\dbinom n2+\dbinom n1=\dbinom{n+1}2=\dfrac{n(n+1)}2$ paths in a tree $T=(V,E)$ with $|V|\ge1$.